# when Implementing Google pay"This transaction may be risky. For your safety, it cant be completed at this time"

Tags: payment-gateway, google-pay

I am facing a problem with Google pay integration(in-app payment) in android app. When I make a request to transact I am getting the error for merchant upi id there will be "This transaction may be risky.For your safety,it cant be completed at this time" and other upi id this issue will be facing
"You have exceeded the maximum transaction amount set by your bank" even though that is my first transaction. And when I try to send amount directly from Google pay it works.

This is the Google pay's in-app payment resource.

```js
Uri uri =
    new Uri.Builder()
        .scheme("upi")
        .authority("pay")
        .appendQueryParameter("pa", "your-merchant-vpa@xxx")
        .appendQueryParameter("pn", "your-merchant-name")
        .appendQueryParameter("mc", "your-merchant-code")
        .appendQueryParameter("tr", "your-transaction-ref-id")
        .appendQueryParameter("tn", "your-transaction-note")
        .appendQueryParameter("am", "your-order-amount")
        .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
        .build();

// Sign the uri as specified
String signature = someSignatureFunction(uri);

uri.buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter("sign", signature);
```